# Sed replace character tab delimited csv

Tags: shell, csv, unix, ssh, sed

I am very new to shell scripting and having issue replacing character of tab delimited csv.

I want to convert the csv to text file and  change the delimiter from tab to `~` , i tried below code but the delimiter turns out different some like japanese char+" instead of `~`.

`sed 's/\t/\"\~\"/g' test.csv > test.txt`

Appreciate your help.. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry it is sed 's/\t/\"\~\"/g' test.csv > test.txt

Comment: Also i notice if I replace with one character eg.~ it is working fine.. but if 2 or more char eg. "~" the output delimter is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

If it's char for char, use `tr`:

```
cat test.csv | tr '\t' '~' > test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, i cannot use tr as I need to replace with string of character..

Comment: Just found out that file is in utf-16 so i need to convert first in utf-8. After that the script run as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use `iconv` to change encoding to UTF-8:

```sh
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 < test.csv | sed 's/\t/"~"/g' > test.txt
```

`"` and `~` can go unescaped.